# how to create a report between dates in crystal reports (visual studio 2010) ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to create a report in crystal reports filtering between dates.. from a web page i must be able to select two dates "from", "to" and then generate a report that send me the data from the DB between that dates.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Dim crTableLogonInfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim crTableLogonInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo

```
Dim crTables As Tables
Dim crTable As Table

Dim crReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass
```

Dim crReportDocuments As New YourReport(crystal report)
                crReportDocuments.SetParameterValue("@Parameter", Parametervalue)
                ..
                ..

With crConnectionInfo ''(Connection Information)
                .ServerName = ServerName 
                .DatabaseName = DataBaseName
                If Uid <> "" Then
                    .UserID = Uid
                    .Password = pwd
                Else
                    .IntegratedSecurity = True
                End If
            End With

```
        crTables = crReport.Database.Tables

        For Each crTable In crTables
            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
        Next

        cry.ReportSource = crReportDocuments
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the start date and end date parameters to the report.  Then in the "Selection Expert", set it to have your date field be between the `{@Start Date}` and `{@End Date}` parameters.

You may want to look at this to help with passing parameters between .NET and Crystal:
[Parameter to Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767814/parameter-to-crystal-report)