# Parameter to Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

i created a @Month as parameter name in crystal report and just insert to the report header section.

When i run the report always it asks the parameter by showing one box. How i pass through code. My existing code is below

```
MyReport rpt = new MyReport();
var srcData = ; //here i added my LINQ statement to select the data
rpt.SetDataSource(srcData);
ParameterDiscreteValue pdValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
pdValue.Value = combo2.SelectedValue;
rpt.ParameterFields["@Month"].CurrentValues.Add(pdValue);
this.ReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Where i did the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I solved by just removing RefershReport() method of crystalreportviewer

I find from  : http://www.it-sideways.com/2011/10/how-to-disable-parameter-prompt-for.html

Comment: if you don't refresh- you're probably looking at saved data?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working it suggests a typo or something. Try analyzing rpt.ParameterFields (set a breakpoint and watch). Have you got the parameter name correct? Data type?

Comment: ya i got it correct i passed to the combo box selected value. Already combobox selected value return as object

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with adding parameters as well.  Here's an example of what I got working:

```
string ponumber = Request.QueryString["ponumber"].ToString();
string receiptno = Request.QueryString["receiptno"].ToString();

    // Put Away Report

    CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
    CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
    CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "Report3.rpt";
    CrystalReportSource1.EnableCaching = false;

    // This will set the values of my two parameters in the report
    CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, ponumber);
    CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, receiptno);



    TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportServerName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportDatabaseName"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportUserID"];
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WarehouseReportPassword"];

    TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    infos.Add(logOnInfo);
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = infos;

    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportSource1);
    maindiv.Controls.Add(CrystalReportViewer1);


    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```